# Tag/group data inside dataset according to next row

Tags: r

I have a dataset (today 10e5, expected later 10e6 rows).
After grouping, the dataset has been reduced to 60 rows. The reduced dataset looks like this (`db.P.sys.a`):

```
logger ;      d; shift

gl240-03 ;   98; D    
gl240-03  ; 114; D    
gl240-04  ; 107; N1   
gl240-04  ; 112; N2   
gl240-04  ; 113; N1   
gl240-04  ; 113; N2   
gl240-04  ; 114; D    
gl240-04  ; 114; N1   
gl240-04  ; 114; N2   
gl240-04  ; 114; T
```

I need now to create an id who groups observations according to that logic:
(for a same logger), if shift on row n is N2 and shift on row (n+1) is N1 and d on row (n+1) is d+1, then they have the same id.

It looks like this:

```
logger ; d; shift; shift_id
gl240-03;   98;  D; 1
gl240-03;   114;    D;  2
gl240-04;   107;    N1; 3
gl240-04;   112;    N2; 4
gl240-04;   113;    N1; 4
gl240-04;   113;    N2; 6
gl240-04;   114;    N1; 6
gl240-04;   114;    N2; 9
gl240-04;   114;    D;  7
gl240-04;   114;    T;  10
```

To do this I proceed that way:

```
#group by logger, d and shift to get less points
db.P.sys.a<-db.P.sys%>%
  group_by(logger,d,shift)%>%
  summarise()
#create a sequence to tag each futur grouped shifts
db.P.sys.a$shift_id<-seq(1:nrow(db.P.sys.a))
#subset db with only (N1 and N2)
db.P.sys.b<-db.P.sys.a%>%
  filter(shift=="N1"|shift=="N2")
#subset db with remaining shifts (D and T)
db.P.sys.c<-db.P.sys.a%>%
  filter(shift=="D"|shift=="T")
#loop to group the consecutive N2 and N1 shifts but with d+1 change 
for (a in 1:(nrow(db.P.sys.b)-1)){
  if((db.P.sys.b$logger[a]==db.P.sys.b$logger[a+1])&(db.P.sys.b$d[a]==(db.P.sys.b$d[a+1])-1)&(db.P.sys.b$shift[a]=="N2")&(db.P.sys.b$shift[a+1]=="N1") ){
    db.P.sys.b$shift_id[a+1]=db.P.sys.b$shift_id[a]}
}
#row bind D, T, N1 and N2 tagged shifts
db.P.sys.a<-rbind(db.P.sys.b,db.P.sys.c)
#join to remaining data (-> each observations are tagged with a shift_id)
db.P.sys<-left_join(db.P.sys,db.P.sys.a,by=c("logger","d","shift"))
```

So now all rows of the initial dataset are tagged with shift_id.

My question is, is there a more elegant way to do the same ? (without using a for loop, for exemple).
I think, `db.P.sys` is not relevant for the question.

In advance thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `dplyr` approach =

```
library(dplyr)

db.P.sys %>%
  group_by(logger) %>%
  mutate(shift_id = shift == 'N1' & lag(shift, default = first(shift)) == 'N2' & 
                    d - lag(d, default = first(d)) == 1) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(shift_id = cumsum(!shift_id))
```

`shift_id` is kept the same if the current `shift` value is `'N1'` (`shift == 'N1'`) and previous `shift` value is `'N2'` (`lag(shift) == 'N2'`) and the difference between current and `previous` `d` value is 1 (`d - lag(d) == 1`) for each `logger`.